# How to make OpenCV Detect method thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I invoke the following OpenCV method (Emgu CV wrapper), which detects faces, in several threads simultaneously:

```
IntPtr objects = CvInvoke.cvHaarDetectObjects(
                   img.Ptr,
                   haarObj.Ptr,
                   stor.Ptr,
                   scaleFactor,
                   minNeighbors,
                   flag,
                   minSize);
```

I get AccessViolationException. The standard .NET lock is unacceptable here since this method takes almost all a thread lifetime. Any ideas how to make this method work concurrently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use an internal multithreading in OpenCV. For that to work, OpenCV must be built with [Intel TBB](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/). Then when the Detect method is called, it uses multiple threads internally.

Comment: Possibly you know, are the any documentation on OpenCV which say what can be run concurrently and what is no? I need to run several instances of Emgu.CV.CameraCalibration.FindChessboardCorners in different threads (heh, you are also in Kiev :) )

Comment: @sergdev It seems to me that there is no such documentation. The best way to check whether your method supports concurrency is to run it in several threads or view OpenCV source. Or you can just build OpenCV with the TBB support.

Comment: I do in this way now, but since there is no any statement in doc, it might be changed in future without any notification